# Place an imageview on customdialog screen depending on variable

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to place a small image on the top of a big one in a custom dialog.

I want the small one to be placed in a different place depending on a variable, which I called "pos". It contains a int value from 0 to 100, meaning percentage of the dialog width.

If pos = 0, I want to place the image in the left margin of the big one, if pos = 30 it should be placed in the 30% of the screen, starting from the left.

If pos = 50 I want it to able placed right in the middle, being 100 the maximum value for it and placing it in the right margin.

I include a draft to explain myself a bit better.

[image]

I tried with RelativeLayout.LayoutParams but I never get expected output.

Comment: Have you tried `imageView.setLeft(a)`, `imageview.setTop(a)` ... ??

Comment: No I haven't. Are those final coordinates? Because in that case it doesn't work for me since phones have different screen sizes.

Comment: You can use DisplayMetrics to get the screen size and dpi, using that calculate these value. So even for different screen size mobile you set same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler strategy is to extend ImageView, then create a custom image using Canvas commands in the onDraw method that draw the bitmap appropriately on the x axis with a background set to match your layout.

You can determine the width of the custom dialog in the the onMeasure method of your custom ImageView, so the returned bitmap (including empty background) can be the correct width, and the position of the smaller bitmap can be correctly apportioned.

Once you've created the class, which will take just a few minutes, you can add it to your XML layout  with something like:

```
 <com.domain.yourapp.YourCustomerImageView
                android:id="@+id/bitmap_graph"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
```